# Import Custom Functions Into Cypress Tests Error

Tags: javascript, import, export, cypress

**Problem:** When importing custom functions into Cypress, I believe it cannot find the module subjects.

**Subjects Array:**

```
const subjects = [
  "Accounting",
  "Art",
  "Biology",
  "Business"
];
export default subjects;
```

**Code Example:**

```
import { subjects } from "../../../../src/data/subjects.js";
const subject = subjects[Math.floor(Math.random() * subjects.length)];
console.log(subject);
```

**Error:** `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')`

**Note:**

1. I've used Visual Studio Code's gui to obtain folder location.
2. My tsconfig.json in the cypress folder does not have a `baseUrl` key/value pair
3. My tsconfig.json in the root folder does have a `baseUrl: "./src"`, but vs code shows an errors when `subjects` is referenced like `from "src/data/subjects.js"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exporting side of things uses the **default** export, so the import would be without the brackets.

```js
import subjects from "../../../../src/data/subjects.js";
```

or change the export to be a named export

```js
export const subjects = [
  "Accounting",
  "Art",
  "Biology",
  "Business"
];
```